# how to manipulate columns that have certain string

Tags: r

I'm trying to perform a for loop for multiple data sets with R. 
here is what it looks.

```
  USERTYPE BSEC Ttime    mean1    mean2  mean3 route
1        1   10  2096 2279.467 2400.989 2849.6     1
2        1   19  2205 2279.467 2400.989 2849.6     1
3        1   11  2559 2279.467 2400.989 2849.6     1
4        1    8  2138 2279.467 2400.989 2849.6     1
5        7   21  2196 2279.467 2400.989 2849.6     1
6        1   13  1954 2279.467 2400.989 2849.6     1
```

What I want to perform is calculate mean1-Ttime , mean2-Ttime, mean3-Ttime and replace them to mean1, mean2, mean3 respectively.
**The problem is when i perform a for loop for multiple data sets the numbers of the columns with "mean"s are different. for example
some data sets have mean1, mean2, mean3, mean4..... mean10.**

What would be a code for performing substraction process with columns that have a different numbers of "mean"s. I thought about grep function for this but couldn't solve it. I would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `dplyr`, you can use `mutate_at` to apply a function to multiple columns.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with('mean')), ~. - Ttime)

#  USERTYPE BSEC Ttime    mean1    mean2 mean3 route
#1        1   10  2096  183.467  304.989 753.6     1
#2        1   19  2205   74.467  195.989 644.6     1
#3        1   11  2559 -279.533 -158.011 290.6     1
#4        1    8  2138  141.467  262.989 711.6     1
#5        7   21  2196   83.467  204.989 653.6     1
#6        1   13  1954  325.467  446.989 895.6     1
```

In base R we can use `grep` to select columns which has `'mean'` in it and subtract  `Ttime`.

```
cols <- grep('mean', names(df))
df[cols] - df$Ttime
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R one-liner:

```
df[,grepl("mean", names(df)] <-  df[,grepl("mean", names(df)] - df$Time
```

Answer (score 1):

In  `dplyr`, we can also do

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(across(starts_with('mean'), ~ . - Ttime))
```